# Scala - map function to replace negatives with previous number in list

Tags: scala

I have a list of numbers

> [1, 2, 3, -1000, 4, -1000]

I want to write a map function to replace all negative numbers in my list with the previous number (before the negative)

In this case the output will be

> [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]

What is the best way to write this map function?

Comment: What should happen if the first number is negative?

Comment: First number will not be negative

Comment: Also note there may be consecutive negatives
[1, -1000, -1000]
becomes
[1, 1, 1]

Answer (score 4):

```
yourList.foldLeft(List[Int]()) { (acc, i) => if (i >= 0) i :: acc else acc.head :: acc }.reverse
```

will throw an exception if first number is negative.

With thanks to Aivean.

Comment: note that your method will take O(N^2) time, as adding element to the end of the list (as well as getting last element) takes O(N) for `List`.

Comment: Also you are replacing zeroes along with negatives.

Comment: Right again mate. Next time you can edit my posts :)

Comment: I'd suggest instead of using `Vector` accum to use `List`, but in reverse order. Afterwards you can just reverse it. It will still be O(N), but with lower constant comparing to `Vector`.

Comment: Oh well, now you are just going overboard :) What is this, performance hour? The dude probably just wants to have his homework done.

Comment: I don't insist on the last point, just nice to know about this option. In Scala `List` is usually used as accum. Sorry if I tend to overimprove :)

Comment: Reversing the list afterwards will make it O(n*2) though :)

Comment: There is no such thing as O(N * 2). It's the same as O(N). Big O  notation represents the [order of the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  And I assure you, that using Vector makes it something like O(N * 32) (in your words).

Comment: Which makes it bed time for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93118/discussion-between-lodewijk-bogaards-and-aivean).

Answer (score 1):

```
def replaceNegatives(list: List[Int], prev: Int = 0): List[Int] = {
   list match {
     case Nil => Nil
     case (x :: xs) if x < 0 => prev :: replaceNegatives(xs, prev)
     case x :: xs => x :: replaceNegatives(xs, x)
   }
}
```

Example:

```
scala> replaceNegatives(List(1, 2, 3, -1000, 4, -1000))
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
```

The second argument (`prev`) is optional;  it is the default value to use if the first item in the list is negative.

Comment: Your method is not tail-recursive, so it will fail on large input.